# Filter text without HTML tags in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-filter

I have a simple AngularJS app which consumes a JSON array of objects like this:

```
$scope.faq = [
 { id: 1, question: "What is the meaning of life?", answer: "42"},
 { id: 2, question: "What <em>is<em> 1+1?", answer: "4"}
]
```

In my HTML I have an ng-repeat with a basic filter coming from a text input like this

```
ng-repeat="qa in faq | filter:searchText"
```

The problem is I want the search to filter while ignoring the HTML tags in the JSON objects, so that searching for the phrase "what is" will return both objects instead of just the first one. How do I change the filter to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

write your custom filter

in html:

```
ng-repeat="qa in faq | customFilter"
```

in js:

```
angular.module('youModule', []).
  filter('customFilter', function() {
    return function(input) {
      var out;
      //parse your strings(find <tag> and exclude it) and push in out variable
      return out;
    }
  });
```

**UPD**
you can transmit in custom filter not only input value (you can add parameter, such as 'searchText')
html: `ng-repeat="qa in faq | customFilter:searchString"`

js:   `return function(input, searchString) {`

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are better ways, but at least this is fairly simple:

```
return $('<div>').html(value).text();
```

non-jQuery version:

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML = value;
return div.innerText;
```

Create a filter using either of these and put it before your `filter:searchText`.